# Get the clicked element ID in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery like :

```
jQuery("#id1,#id2").click(function(){
     //do stuff
});
```

I am checking that either id1 or id2 is clicked then do something. But in the function I need to get which ID is clicked.
Can somebody help me in that?

Comment: I don't know why someone down-voted your question, it was a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
var idClicked = jQuery(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpler version is:

```
var idClicked = this.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a simpler code:
Add the same class to the elements you want to attach the click listener and when clicked just retrieve the attribute's value.

```
jQuery(".my-class").click(function(){
    var element_id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
});
```